# haandroid database table not created in other activitiies?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

i am using sqllite database in android with android studio i have make a manager class for every activity that is responsible for creating table and inserting records my bloodmanager class code is this and on insertion it return id of inserted rows sucessfully

```
public class PersonalManager  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       public static final String DATABASE="mydb";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

public MedicineManger(Context context)
{

    super( context, DATABASE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


     public static abstract class MedicineEntry implements BaseColumns
{
    public static final String TABLE="Medicine";
    public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String type="type";
    public static final String dosage="dosage";
}

public static final String CREATE="CREATE TABLE "+ MedicineEntry.TABLE+"( "+
        MedicineEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
        MedicineEntry.NAME+" TEXT,"+
        MedicineEntry.type+" TEXT,"+
        MedicineEntry.dosage+" INTEGER )";

  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE);
}
```

i extented `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

the above code works for one class but to create another table for patientManager, session manager etc i copy past the same code but during insertion it return id  `-1`  my isertion in like thaT

```
      String name=edName.getText().toString();
            String type=edtype.getText().toString();
            long dosage=Long.valueOf(eddosage.getText().toString());

            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(MedicineEntry.NAME, name);
            cv.put(MedicineEntry.type, type);
            cv.put(MedicineEntry.dosage, dosage);

            long id=sqldb.insert(MedicineEntry.TABLE, null, cv);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Record Added Generated id is : "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
```

}
BUT FOR WORKS ONLY FOR 1 CLASS SAME CODE WITH DIFFERENT TABLE NAME AND FEILDS NOT WORKS IN other activities to create and insert values , can you please tell me how to manage that to create multiple table for every activity

Comment: same code but i changed pnly table name and feilds

Comment: i think MedicineEntry._ID is missing in your abstract class MedicineEntry.

Comment: THE ABOVE IS WORKING CODE IT ENTERS ID BY SELF TO CREATE ANOTHER TABLE FOR OTHER ACTIVITITES I USED THE SAME CODE BUT NOT CREAITING TABLE FOR SESSION , PATIENT , BLOOD MANAGER ETC

Comment: I TRIED HARDCODDED WAY TO ` db.execSQL("Create table blood (id primary key ,  blood text , count long);");`  in other activities but not works

Comment: did you try to uninstall and the reinstall  the app again.?

Comment: same code work only in 1 manager class that i used first out of 4\

Comment: mean if i use 3 after reinstalling it works for 3 only but no for others vice versa on reinstallation but i want to mkake it to work for every 4 classes

Comment: no.
you should have to create a Sqlitehelper class in which you should create all the tables and methods related to sqlite database.

Comment: OK I AM CREATING ONLY 1 SQL HELPER CLASS INSTEAD OF MULTIPLE

Comment: yes and create all the tables on that single class.

Comment: GREAT I HAVE ADDED THEM IN 1 HELPER CLASS THIS WORKS\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to create a Sqlitehelper class in which you should create all the tables and methods related to sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think about to use a Datasource class, and use it in each class you need
[Data Source android](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/sql/DataSource.html)